# Firebase ionic2-rc0 and rollup - “rollup: Use of `eval` is strongly discouraged”

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2, rollupjs

I've updated my ionic app from beta 11 to rc0. So it means I've switched from angular2 rc4 to angular2 stable, from typescript 1.8 to 2 and using the rollupjs module bundler.

I have configured AngularFire2 according to this blog post:
[Getting Started with Ionic 2 RC0, Firebase 3 + AngularFire 2](https://playcode.org/getting-started-with-ionic-2-rc0-firebase-3-angularfire-2/)

I'm not able to compile and getting this error:

> rollup: Use ofeval(in
>   c:\XXX\node_modules\angularfire2\node_modules\firebase\firebase.js) is
>   strongly discouraged, as it poses security risks and may cause issues
>   with minification. See
>   https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#avoiding-eval
>   for more details

Anyone knows what's going on and how to tackle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long-term, the solution is for Firebase to remove direct `eval` from their code, as it's not actually necessary here (it's just being used to parse JSON. `JSON.parse` is much faster, and support is basically a non-issue these days).

In the meantime, a possible (albeit hacky) workaround might be to convert that `eval` into an *indirect* `eval` (see the [troubleshooting note](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#avoiding-eval) to understand the difference), using [rollup-plugin-replace](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-replace):

```js
// rollup.config.js
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';
// ...etc

export default {
  // ...other config...
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve({...}),
    commonjs({...}),
    replace({
      include: 'node_modules/firebase/firebase.js',
      values: {
        'eval(' : '[eval][0]('
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think I have some more severe errors elsewhere and that's why I'm not able to compile.
I think the use of eval is not a breaking error so I'll keep things as they are.

Thanks again,

Answer (score 5):

You can disable this warning in rollup config:

```js
// rollup.config.js

export default {
  // ...other config...
  onwarn: function (message) {
    if (/Use of `eval` \(in .*\/node_modules\/firebase\/.*\) is strongly discouraged/.test(message)) {
      return;
    }
    console.error(message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning can be suppressed with `rollup.config.js`:

```js
export default {
    onwarn(warning, warn)
    {
        if (warning.code == 'EVAL' && /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]firebase[\\/]/.test(warning.id)) return;

        warn(warning);
    }
};
```

The pattern `[\\/]` is used to catch the path delimiter on both Windows and *nix.